# Sizeof string vs sizeof string pointer

Tags: c

In the following code:

```
char *title = "VP";
printf("Sizeof title: %zd | Sizeof *title: %zd | Strlen: %zd\n", sizeof title, sizeof *title, strlen(title));
```

> Sizeof title: 8 | Sizeof *title: 1 | Strlen: 2

It seems like the `sizeof title` operates on the pointer to the string (8 bytes for me), and the `strlen(title)` predictably gives me 2.

Why does the `sizeof *title` produce 1 when dereferencing the pointer rather than 3 (the byte-length of the string)? For example, why does it do that instead of what it would produce for:

```
printf("%zd\n", sizeof("VP"));
// 3
```

Comment: See [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array).

Comment: samuelbrody1249, Since `title` is a pointer, not a _string_, why expect `sizeof title` to return the size of something it is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a pointer is *always* the size of the pointer itself, not what it points to. That's because `sizeof` is mostly a compile-time operator (the result is evaluated by the compiler) and the compiler can't know what a pointer might point to at run-time.

As for `sizeof *title` it's the same as `sizeof title[0]` which is a single `char`. And the size of a `char` is `1` (it's specified to *always* be `1` by the way, no matter the actual bit-width).

Lastly about `sizeof "VP"`. In C all literal strings are really *arrays* of characters, including the terminating null character. So the literal string `"VP"` is an array of three characters, hence its size is `3`.

---

To make the answer a little bit more complete, I say that the `sizeof` operator is *mostly* compile-time. That of course can't be true for [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), where the compiler must insert code to store the actual size of the array in a way that it can be fetched at run-time. If the array decays to a pointer, then all you have is the pointer and again `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer itself.

And a note about string literal arrays. While they are technically *non*-constant arrays, they still can't be modified. Attempting to modify a string literal leads to *undefined behavior*. Literal strings are thus, in effect, read-only.

Comment: -- thanks for that. What would be the suggested way that you could do the runtime equivalent of `sizeof` for the above to get `3` ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 A variable-length array, as in `size_t length = 3; char array[length]; strcpy(array, "VP");` Then `sizeof array` will be calculated at run-time. However, once the array has decayed to a pointer, then `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer.

Comment: thanks. What if the string literal is defined in the global scope (and stored in `.data`) is that still the same or any different?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 All strung literals are "global", the arrays never go out of scope during the life-time of the program. So you can always use pointers to literal strings.

Comment: Also worth noting that `%zd` is not the correct specifier, it should have been `%zu`.

Comment: "they still can't be modified." --> more like "modification should not be attempted."  Attempting to modify a _string literal_ might work.  It is UB.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili ok, but then why are there so many references online that say to use `%zd` ? https://keramida.wordpress.com/2006/04/03/how-big-is-a-size/.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I don't know why they are using the wrong specifier. You can see the table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for correct specifiers.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 There *is* a "signed `size_t`" in some operating systems. For example `ssize_t` which is defined in POSIX (operating systems like Linux or macOS). Then `%zd` is valid. But for the normal C-standard `size_t` it needs to be an unsigned specifier (like `%zu`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude out of curiosity then, why is something like `CHAR_MAX` or other constants in `limits.h` not `%zu` but `%d` ? Oh, I think because the preprocessor substitutions default to integer if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 That's correct, those macros expand to plain `int` values (when possible).

Answer (score 1):

The type of `title` is `char *`, so the type of `*title` is `char`, *not* `char [3]`.  Thus , `sizeof *title` is equivalent to `sizeof (char)`, which is 1.

`title` isn’t the string, it just points to the first element of the string.